# RDS Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdo, laravel-5.1, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect my Laravel 5.1 application using rds mysql. But it ended up in getting

***SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused***

The same rds database is using in other EC2 instance. But it works fine there. Only difference between two EC2 is the security group. As i come to notice that 3306 port should be open for mysql. I make it open in my security group. But still getting the same error.
Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: May be your RDS's security group doesn't allow access from the 2nd EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with csf.

```
sudo  nano /etc/csf/csf.conf
```

Add 3306 in TCPIN ports. 
And restart using

```
sudo csf -r
```